# Google Play Games Services проблема с аутентификацией

Tags: android, unity3d, разработка-игр, google-play-console, google-play-services

Есть проблема в Unity с сервисами Google Play.

Я встраиваю в свою игру сервисы, код есть, в консоли всё настроено. Проблема в следующем: при в ходе в игру у меня как и запланировано активируются гугл плэй сервисы (то есть всплывает окошко)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но дальше ничего не происходит.

Приложение уже опубликовано как бета и по идее проблема с тестировщиками неуместна (хотя и так везде свой аккаунт как тестировщика добавил)

Вот мой код:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using GooglePlayGames;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;

public class MG : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Start()
    {
        PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder()
            .RequestEmail()
            .Build();
        PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
        PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
        PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
        Authenticate();
    }

    public void Authenticate()
    {
        Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) =>{ });
     }
}
```

Но я уверен дело не в коде, а в каких-то мелочах в консоли.

---

Я вывел логи в момент входа в сервисы[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также хочу отметить, что игра опубликована в бета тестировании, и мой аккаунт внесён в список тестеров как в google play concole, так и в сам проект сервисов.

Ещё читал документацию, и там говорилось про APP ID, но я его в юнити нигде не добавлял. Или оно по дефолту встроено в моей игре...? Также ничего не делал с client ID.

---

@Suvitruf ничего подобного не нашел
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вывести `success`, то он чему равен?

Comment: И вообще, покажите полные логи плагина.

Comment: Если вывести `success` то false

Comment: @Suvitruf что за логи?

Comment: Логи игры. Google Play Games плагин очень много чего в логах выводит.

Comment: @Suvitruf это у Unity на до искать?

Comment: В логах Android Studio.

Comment: @Suvitruf я все никак не могу найти эти логи в Android studio, можете сказать где это найти?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/images/debug/logcat_2x.png

Comment: Package name - это оно и есть. А ключом вы релизным подписываете?

Comment: @Suvitruf типо keystore? Да

Comment: то есть package name это pakage ID. Тогда где я должен указать APP ID?

Comment: я проверил, pakage name введен верно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Честно не знаю как, но я сделал это.

Возможно это из-за того, что я в консоли разработчика повторно связал приложение, но я просто указал Package name не выбирая того что мне предлагало, и ввел тот SHA1, который мне вывели логи (вроде бы такой же как и в консоли)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С недавних пор разрабатываю свою вторую игру у которой тоже не происходил вход в GPGS, и я также переСвязал его и все сработало (сначала я починил эту игру, а потом первую).

Answer (score 0):

> Ещё читал документацию, и там говорилось про APP ID, но я его в юнити нигде не добавлял. Или оно по дефолту встроено в моей игре...? Также ничего не делал с client ID.

Там же на [гитхабе](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity) написано как это сделать.

Сверху в Unity в меню выбрать: **Window > Google Play Games > Setup... > Android Setup**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вставить туда json из dev консоли вашей игры в Google Play.

Comment: package id и ключ, которым подписываете .apk, точно релизные?

Comment: запутался. Не понял откуда надо взять Client ID, это случайно не OAuth2?

Comment: @АндрейАлександрович для гейм сервисов Client ID не нужен.

Comment: хз, а package ID я должен вводить где-то?

Comment: Player Settings -> Other settings -> Bundle Identifier.